# php text file parsing

Tags: php, parsing, text

i have a text file named file.txt. and the contents of file.txt is as follows :

```
tarek
shourav
```

when i run the following code

```
<?

$a=file('file.txt');

foreach ($a as $b) {
echo $b;
echo "<br>";
echo strlen($b);
echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

it gives the output

```
tarek 
7
shourav
7
```

but it should give the output

```
tarek
5
shourav
7
```

can anybody please tell me,where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have spaces or tabs in your file? Are you sure you are looking at the right file?

Comment: @Sjoerd might be right. Use `trim`.

Comment: Agree with @Sjoerd, you probably have trailing or leading whitespace. Try doing trim($b) to remove it.

Comment: yes I am sure there is no space.But I dont understand why the stringlenth of first text of file.txt is everytime orginal strlen +2

Comment: Dump $a once and you will see what unexpected content is in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guessing you have CR/LF at the end of your first line

```
$a=file('file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```